# is scanning your router's ip(the default gateway) or is just a harmless thing that I can do

Tags: linux, nmap

is performing an nmap on your default gateway ip illegal or it is legal because it is your router's ip address?

I wanted to exploit the vulnerabilities but wanted to check first what I was doing was legal or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am not a lawyer nor is this legal advice*

You can nmap scan your own local router IP address with nmap as it is your residential network. That is explicitly mentioned here in the [nmap book](https://nmap.org/book/legal-issues.html#:%7E:text=Network%20probing%20or%20port%20scanning,any%20reason%2C%20is%20strictly%20prohibited.).